# Loops not displaying correct output Java

Tags: java

I have a program that is supposed to take a message, then rotate the letters all possible ways (eg a becomes b, a becomes c, a becomes d...), then print all of these out. So if you typed hi into it, it should print out ij, jk, kl, lm, etc. However, it only prints out some of these rotations. Here is the output I get for typing a:
a
b
d
g
k
p
v

Here is the code that is supposed to rotate the letters, then display them. Before this I have code that puts all of the characters in the message into an array of integers representing the letters (1 for a, 2 for b...27 for " "). Can someone please help me correct whatever mistake I made and learn how not to make it next time?
Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Decoder {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] messageIntArray = new int[999999];
    int[] messageWordIntArray = new int [1000000];
    int letterCount = -1;
    char messageChar;
    String message = "";
    boolean moreLines = true;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r;
    String rotatedMessage = "";
    //[boolean running = true;


        System.out.println("Enter message" + "\nMake sure you have a line at the end of your message with only a period");

        while (moreLines) {

        String line = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (line.equals(".")) {
        moreLines=false;
        } else {
            message = message + line + " ";

        }
}

        for (int q= 0; q<message.length(); q++){
            messageChar= message.charAt(q);

            if (messageChar == 'a' || messageChar == 'A' || messageChar == 'A') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 1;

            } else if (messageChar == 'b' || messageChar == 'B') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 2;
            } else if (messageChar == 'c' || messageChar == 'C') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 3;
            } else if (messageChar == 'd' || messageChar == 'D') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 4;
            } else if (messageChar == 'e' || messageChar == 'E') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 5;
            } else if (messageChar == 'f' || messageChar == 'F') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 6;
            } else if (messageChar == 'g' || messageChar == 'G') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 7;
            } else if (messageChar == 'h' || messageChar == 'H') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 8;
            } else if (messageChar == 'i' || messageChar == 'I') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 9;
            } else if (messageChar == 'j' || messageChar == 'J') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 10;
            } else if (messageChar == 'k' || messageChar == 'K') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 11;
            } else if (messageChar == 'l' || messageChar == 'L') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 12;
            } else if (messageChar == 'm' || messageChar == 'M') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 13;
            } else if (messageChar == 'n' || messageChar == 'N') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 14;
            } else if (messageChar == 'o' || messageChar == 'O') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 15;
            } else if (messageChar == 'p' || messageChar == 'P') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 16;
            } else if (messageChar == 'q' || messageChar == 'Q') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 17;
            } else if (messageChar == 'r' || messageChar == 'R') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 18;
            } else if (messageChar == 's' || messageChar == 'S') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 19;
            } else if (messageChar == 't' || messageChar == 'T') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 20;
            } else if (messageChar == 'u' || messageChar == 'U') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 21;
            } else if (messageChar == 'v' || messageChar == 'V') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 22;
            } else if (messageChar == 'w' || messageChar == 'W') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 23;
            } else if (messageChar == 'x' || messageChar == 'X') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 24;
            } else if (messageChar == 'y' || messageChar == 'Y') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 25;
            } else if (messageChar == 'z' || messageChar == 'Z') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 26;
            } 
            else if (messageChar == ' ') {
                messageIntArray[q] = 27;
            } 
            letterCount++;

            int letter = messageIntArray[q];
            messageWordIntArray[letterCount] = letter;


        }








            for (int t = 0; t<26; t++) {
                for (r=0; r < letterCount; r++){

                if (messageWordIntArray[r] <=25 ) {
                    messageWordIntArray[r] = messageWordIntArray[r] + t;
                } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 26 && t>0) {
                    messageWordIntArray[r] = 0;
                    messageWordIntArray[r] = messageWordIntArray[r] + t;
                }




            if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 1) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "a";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 2) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "b";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 3) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "c";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 4) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "d";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 5) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "e";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 6) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "f";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 7) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "g";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 8) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "h";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 9) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "i";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 10) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "j";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 11) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "k";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 12) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "l";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 13) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "m";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 14) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "n";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 15) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "o";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 16) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "p";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 17) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "q";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 18) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "r";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 19) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "s";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 20) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "t";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 21) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "u";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 22) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "v";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 23) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "w";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 24) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "x";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 25) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "y";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 26) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + "z";
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 27) {
                rotatedMessage = rotatedMessage + " ";
            }




                }

            System.out.print(rotatedMessage+"\n");
            rotatedMessage="";

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Change the ifelse statement as switch statement. It may reduce all problems

Comment: You don't need the else if statements. Just simple math will simplify and beautify some of this awful code. Something like, `rotatedMessage += (char)(messageWordIntArray[r] + 1 + 'a')`.

Comment: On a semi-related note, using char and potentially casting between int + 97 and char might be even easier. Edit: Hovercraft that's sneaky with + 'a'

Comment: Please... please take @HovercraftFullOfEels suggestion.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels if i replace the 27 else if statements with `rotatedMessage += (char)(messageWordIntArray[r] + 1 + 'a')` , still get weird output...

Comment: pleas show the code where you create and fill `messageWordIntArray` I suspect you maybe encoding the characters inconsistenly

Comment: @vandale okay theres the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if (messageWordIntArray[r] <=25 ) {
         messageWordIntArray[r] = messageWordIntArray[r] + t;
   } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 26 && t>0) {
         messageWordIntArray[r] = 0;
         messageWordIntArray[r] = messageWordIntArray[r] + t;
   }
```

to

```
if (messageWordIntArray[r] <=25 ) {
         messageWordIntArray[r]++;
   } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] == 26 && t>0) {
         messageWordIntArray[r] = 0;
   }
```

Since you don't reinitialize the array you keep adding to it.

Also, as Hoover Craft mentioned, remember that all `char`s are numbersand that `'a'+1 =='b'`, it will greatly clean up your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            if (messageWordIntArray[r] <=25 ) {
                messageWordIntArray[r] = messageWordIntArray[r] + t;
            } else if (messageWordIntArray[r] >26 && t>0) {
                messageWordIntArray[r%26] = messageWordIntArray[r%26] + t;
            }
```